# how to monitor multiple systems in nagios

Tags: networking, monitoring, nagios

I am very new to nagios 3.4.4. I was able to set up and monitor the localhost machine. I tired to copy the localhost config to create a new host, which didnt work. Is there a place where i can find example of a config file monitoring mutiple host? Or a tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: read [the Nagios quickstart guide](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart.html)!

Comment: Better yet: read everything under The Basics in docs

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to install and configure NRPE (or NSClient++ for Windows) on the remote hosts if you want to check load, swap, and other things that are not external-facing services.  There are also a lot of plugins that will check the health of well-known external facing services (http, smtp, ssh, etc.).

The Debian and Ubuntu repositories, EPEL, etc., have NRPE.

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details

Comment: Unix & Linux boxes can return values for load, swap, disk space and other simple metrics with an SNMP daemon -- NRPE isn't required for this.

Comment: Fair enough;  I started with Nagios by monitoring exclusively Windows.  I still like NRPE for the ability to write custom checks.

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, NRPE is awesome -- but it's quite heavyweight for things like load and disk.

Answer (score 1):

Also, once you have glanced over the Nagios guide as @Flup suggests, I would recommend you to have a look at the amazing [NagiosQL](http://www.nagiosql.org/) project. It makes it all a bit easier...